# How would do I get the value counts of each item in specified columns of my dataframe and still maintain the index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a histogram of certain grouped objects. So to give some context, I have a main data frame `df`, and I query it based on some values and assign that to `df_q`. Now with `df_q`, I create an index to id this group. What I would like to do now is get the value count of each item of a particular column. So if I have:

```
In [128]: df_q
Out[128]:
        annual_base_delta_range_ten  annual_base_delta_range_three
row_id
10010                             3                              5
10010                             5                             11
10010                             6                             15
10010                             5                             11
10010                             5                             11
10010                             5                             12
10010                             6                             14
10010                             6                             16
10010                             4                              9
10010                             4                              9
```

I know that I can do something like this on each series:

```
In [129]: df_q.annual_base_delta_range_ten.value_counts()
Out[129]:
5    4
6    3
4    2
3    1
Name: annual_base_delta_range_ten, dtype: int64
```

But I would like to have a dataframe that looks like `df_q` (i.e, same index of `row_id` and same column names with the addition of two new columns of value counts).

**Edit**

Here is what I would like my desired result to look like:

```
delta_ten  |  delta_10_count |  delta_three  |  delta_three_count
  3               1                 5               1
  4               2                 9               2
  5               4                 11              3
```

and so forth... and with all the same row_id as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge (i.e., join) your original data frame with each `value_counts` series, using the source column as a merge key.

```
col = 'annual_base_delta_range_ten'
df.merge(df[col].value_counts().to_frame('{}_value_counts'.format(col)),
         left_on='annual_base_delta_range_ten', right_index=True)
```

```
        annual_base_delta_range_ten  annual_base_delta_range_three  annual_base_delta_range_ten_value_counts
row_id                                                                                                      
10010                             3                              5                                         1
10010                             5                             11                                         4
10010                             5                             11                                         4
10010                             5                             11                                         4
10010                             5                             12                                         4
10010                             6                             15                                         3
10010                             6                             14                                         3
10010                             6                             16                                         3
10010                             4                              9                                         2
10010                             4                              9                                         2
```

Comment: Great, I knew that merge should be done but I couldn't just get it right. Just one more question, how would you recommend removing duplicate items though? I don't mind having more blank columns to satisfy the neighbor (delta_range_three) but the extra numbers just looks unpythonic

Comment: @Maksim, sorry, don't understand. What duplicates are you referring to? Can you update your question with the desired output for your sample data?

Comment: what I'm referring to is how there are duplicate value counts of same number. Ideally I'd want it to just have a sorted column with a count next to each. So *_range_ten should have only one 3,4,5 and 6. It's neighbor count column should then have, 1,2,4, and 3. Does that better clarify?

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer but not a one-liner, use value_counts() with map.
EDIT: As @Igor Raush suggested, we can pass a series to map so to_dict is not necessary.

```
val_count_ten = df.annual_base_delta_range_ten.value_counts()
val_count_three = df.annual_base_delta_range_three.value_counts()
df['val_count_ten'] = df.annual_base_delta_range_ten.map(val_count_ten)
df['val_count_three'] = df.annual_base_delta_range_three.map(val_count_three)
```

Gives you

```
    row_id  annual_base_delta_range_ten annual_base_delta_range_three      val_count_ten    val_count_three
0   10010   3                           5                                  1                1
1   10010   5                           11                                 4                3
2   10010   6                           15                                 3                1
3   10010   5                           11                                 4                3
4   10010   5                           11                                 4                3
5   10010   5                           12                                 4                1
6   10010   6                           14                                 3                1
7   10010   6                           16                                 3                1
8   10010   4                           9                                  2                2
9   10010   4                           9                                  2                2
```

Comment: Great solution. Note that you can pass a series to `map()`, so `to_dict()` is unnecessary. Also, `df.assign(val_count_ten=..., val_count_three=...)` could turn this into a (long) one-liner.

Comment: @Igor Raush, Thanks for the inputs. Yeah didn't think of using map on series directly:)

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Also, what is the to_dict() an attribute too? Could I instead use my own dict?

Comment: Pandas Series.map maps the values of a series using input that can be another series, dictionary or function. So here we are mapping the output of value counts to the column